# DIY 2x4 Treadmill

Tags: wood

I'm looking to make a nice cheap 2x4-based treadmill for my basement, in fact, almost exactly like what [this guy did](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_9fzXg44aU).

The problem I'm trying to wrap my head around concerns the belt/roller hardware. I would build mine to have a (manually) adjustable incline. I could lay it flat or hke it up on a safety block and go perhaps as high as 15°, etc.

- What could I use for the belt and where might I find it?
- What could I use for the rollers and where might I find them?
- **Most importantly**: How do these rollers get adjustable tension so that they "feel" correct when at a flat (0°) incline, and "feel" correct at another incline?

Comment: Getting a broken treadmill on craigslist free is a good way to source parts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hobby project.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch (+1) - just curious, aren't all DIY projects technically hobby projects (and vice versa)?!

Comment: Have a look at the help center, diy is the domain but the scope of the site is "home improvement"

Comment: @smeeb- Many sites have parts exclusively for treadmills. I know they sell replacement belts and rollers, but everything in between. Search E-bay and Amazon to get an idea of pricing and such. I couldn't think of "common" items that could be repurposed for a belt. Maybe sleeved 3/4" schedule 40 steel pipe for rollers? How'd the pool demo go?

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. The question is a DIY project at it's very best. I am vaguely positive of having responded to several questions were the project entailed modifying or substituting parts.